# How to change the value of inlines in a Django Admin form dynamically?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make the display of inline forms dynamic in Django according to the value of the "content_type" column, but I'm not succeeding. I've already tried overriding the get_inlines, get_inline_instance, and, finally, methods, as shown below:

```
class XInline(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = X
    fields = ["title", "some_field"]
    extra = 1


class YInline(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = Y
    fields = ["title", "some_field"]
    extra = 1


class ZInline(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = Z
    fields = ["title", "some_field"]
    extra = 1


class MyModelAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["id", "content_type"]

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if (obj): self.inlines = self.get_inlines()
        for inline in self.inlines:
            if obj.content_type.model == "x":
                self.inlines = [XInline]
            elif obj.content_type.model == "y":
                self.inlines = [YInline]
            elif obj.content_type.model == "z":
                self.inlines = [ZInline]

        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Ps.: that `content_type` is a ForeignKey of ContentType from `from django.contrib.contenttypes.models`